# Oracle SQL - Deriving user status based on actions and dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I've a table on employees' name, their actions, and the date of the actions. I want to derive a status on whether or not they are in the company for a particular year based on some of the date of their actions. How can I do that? (I think the biggest challenge is that all the dates are listed in a single column, there's no explicit 'start' and 'end' date column)

**Sample Dataset**

```
|Name|Date|Action|
|--|--|--|
|John|09/08/15|Some Action|
|John|02/02/16|Started Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies|
|John|08/03/16|Some Action|
|John|17/04/17|Some Action|
|John|31/06/18|Graduated from Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies|
|John|01/03/19|Some Action|
|Mary|07/03/15|Some Action|
|Mary|02/08/16|Some Action|
|Mary|07/03/17|Started Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies|
|Mary|02/09/17|Some Action|
|Mary|08/05/18|Graduated from Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies|
```

**What I want**

```
|User|Year|Status|
|--|--|--|
|John|2015|With Company|
|John|2016|On Full-Time Studies|
|John|2017|On Full-Time Studies|
|John|2018|On Full-Time Studies|
|John|2019|With Company|
|John|2020|With Company|
|Mary|2015|With Company|
|Mary|2016|With Company|
|Mary|2017|On Full-Time Studies|
|Mary|2018|On Full-Time Studies|
|Mary|2019|With Company|
|Mary|2020|With Company|
```

**Or alternatively, just ppl not with the company for the year**

```
|User|Year|
|--|--|
|John|2016|
|John|2017|
|John|2018|
|Mary|2017|
|Mary|2018|
```

For simplicity, we can ignore the weird start/end date of the studies. Even if the employee started their studies on 29 Dec 2015, we can take it that they are on full-time studies for 2015.

Answer (score 0):

I filtered the actions and used connect be leve to get the year range. Please see and use the below query as reference.  Used distinct to avoid duplicates in connect by level. Not sure whether this is the right way, there could be better way.

Query:

```
with employees as 
(
  select 'John' as Name, to_date('03/04/2015','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Started Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies' as action from dual union all
  select 'John' as Name, to_date('03/04/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Some Action' as action from dual union all
  select 'John' as Name, to_date('03/04/2018','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Graduated from Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies' as action from dual union all
  
  select 'Mary' as Name, to_date('03/04/2016','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Some Action' as action from dual union all 
  select 'Mary' as Name, to_date('03/04/2017','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Started Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies' as action from dual union all 
  select 'Mary' as Name, to_date('03/04/2019','dd/mm/yyyy') as date_, 'Graduated from Company Sponsored Full-Time Studies' as action from dual 
)

select 
distinct name, min_year_ + level Year_
from
(
  select
    name, 
    min(extract(year from date_))-1 min_year_, 
    max(extract(year from date_)) max_year_,
    max(extract(year from date_)) - (min(extract(year from date_))-1) y_diff
  from
    employees
  where
    action like ('%Full-Time Studies%')
    or action like ('%Graduated%')
  group by
    name
  order by
    name
) emp_t1
connect by level <= y_diff
order by
name
```

Fiddle URL : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b923b7b891f7320ffa5768db8c378328

Comment: There are a lot of different actions. Just using group by alone is not sufficient to retrieve the time period related to two specific action of interest.

Comment: filtering the action in where clause before group by wont help?

Comment: It's not enough. Imagine that the studies start in 2015 and is completed in 2019. Grouping by name and date, and then filtering by "WHERE Action in ('Started study', 'Ended study')" would mean that 2016, 2017, and 2018 will be missing from my output. I need the entire period which he was away (in years) to be reflected.

Comment: so you want the years between "start studies" and "graduation" by employee. will try.

Comment: Updated query using in connect by level. Pls check.

Comment: Thanks! I think it should work, just that the query is running extremely slow on my database with 7 million records, even after I set it to fetch first 5 rows only. I suspect it's probably running some operations on the entire database. Let me play around to see how I can speed things up. Thanks!

Comment: Wow 7 million. I added another query in the fiddle.  There is a change in the  way actions are filtered using like and used another temp table. Please see if that works better than the first one. 
[fiddle query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=36f4934a8da94c03e54945224247b382)

And, please use IN instead of LIKE if text value in action are constants.